# query array into multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

So I'm trying to run a query and when I get the array, I want to reorganize it. Or can I possibly run a query to get the result that I want?
Basically how can I get this array:

```
array() {
 [0] => array() {
  UID    => 1,
  gameid => 334613
 },
 [1] => array() {
  UID    => 2,
  gameid => 704234
 },
 [2] => array() {
  UID => 3,
  gameid => 704234
 }
}
```

to become this:

```
$array = array (
    (334613) => array (
        [0] => 1
    ),
    (704234) => array (
        [0] => 2,
        [1] => 3
    )
);
```

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$arr = array(
    array(
      "UID"    => 1,
      "gameid" => 334613
    ),
    array(
      "UID"    => 2,
      "gameid" => 704234
    ),
    array(
      "UID" => 3,
      "gameid" => 704234
    )
);


$result = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $v){
    if( !isset( $c[ $v["gameid"] ] ) ) $c[ $v["gameid"] ] = array(); //Will also work without this line. 
    $c[ $v["gameid"] ][] = $v["UID"];       
    return $c;
}, array());

print_r( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [334613] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [704234] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

You can also use the classic `foreach`

```
$result = array();
foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    $result[ $val["gameid"] ][] = $val["UID"];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple foreach loop will do

```
$array = [ ... ]; // your array
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $game) {
    $result[ $game['gameid'] ][] = $game['UID'];
}

var_dump($result);
```